# Dropdown box posting wrong values

Tags: php, forms

I'm hoping this is something small.  After combing through this for a couple hours and trying all sorts of variations I've decided to let the pros have a crack at it.
I've got a page setup to administer a database easily.  Basically just to update a row or delete it. For each row I've got a checkbox to update the row, check box to delete, three columns of info from database and then two columns with dropdown boxes to change values.
The issue is that no matter what values I choose from the dropdown, it always posts the same values. Using print_r($_POST) I can see that it's actually returning the wrong value.  Without further ado, the code:

This is at the top of my page (the form post to itself):

```
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    $product = $_POST['product_choice'];
    $status = $_POST['status_choice'];
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $update = $_POST["update"];
    }
    $id = "('" . implode( "','", $checkbox ) . "');" ;
    $sql="UPDATE test_orders SET product='$product',status = '$status' WHERE ordNum IN $id" ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      }
```

And the form:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="frmactive" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">

<!--BUTTONS--> 

<tr>  
<td colspan="6"><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Upate" />
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="5"><strong>Update multiple rows in mysql with checkbox</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Update?</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Delete?</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Order #</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Name</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Job Name</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Product</td>

<td style="background: #ddd; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;">Status</td>


</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>


<tr>
<td align="center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['ordNum']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FF0000" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="delete[]" value="<? echo $rows['ordNum']; ?>" /></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ordNum']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['OrderDesc']; ?></td>
<td>
<select name="product_choice" id="product" style="font-size:10px;">

            <option value="<? echo $rows['product']; ?>" selected="selected"><? echo $rows['product']; ?>
            </option>
            <option value="Color Correction"> Color Correction </option>
            <option value="Basic retouch"> Basic retouch </option>
            <option value="Extensive Retouch"> Extensive Retouch </option>
            <option value="Signature Work"> Signature Work </option>
            <option value="Signature Oil"> Signature Oil </option>
            <option value="Web Design"> Web Design </option>
            <option value="Print Design"> Print Design </option>
            <option value="Other"> Other </option>
          </select>

</td>

<td>
   <select name="status_choice" id="status" style="font-size:10px;">

            <option value="<? echo $rows['status']; ?>" selected="selected"><? echo $rows['status']; ?></option>
            <option value="Order Received"> Order Received </option>
            <option value="in the works"> in the works </option>
            <option value="waiting to upload"> waiting to upload </option>
            <option value="uploading"> uploading </option>
            <option value="ON HOLD"> ON HOLD </option>
            <option value="awaiting decision"> awaiting decision </option>
            <option value="proof sent"> proof sent </option>
            <option value="next invoice"> next invoice </option>
            <option value="waiting images/order"> waiting images/order </option>
            <option value="invoiced"> invoiced </option>
            <option value="complete"> complete </option>
            <option value="paid"> paid </option>
            <option value="making changes"> making changes </option>
          </select>

    </td>

    </tr>



<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the result of print_r($_POST); no matter what options I choose in the dropdowns.  the [product_choice] and [status_choice] are always the same.

```
Array ( [update] => Upate [checkbox] => Array ( [0] => 113 ) [product_choice] => Extensive Retouch [status_choice] => Order Received )
```

thanks for any help.

*******SOLVED********************
Got some help from a friend,  Working good is below

Comment: You __really__ should not be using the `mysql_*` library.

Comment: As @TiesonT. perhaps implies, you are open to SQL injection here.

Comment: I assume you are saying that I should be using POD instead?  I just haven't taken the time to use it yet.  However that still shouldn't play into the current issue though.  Or does it?

Comment: @AndyMcCormick:  It is not causing any issue *today*, but a release of PHP will soon cause this code to stop functioning.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys.  After finally starting to get the hang of php with mysql, of course they would change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

opening foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value)) {
        $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else {
        foreach($value as $key => $value) {
            $_POST[$key][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }
}

//print_r($_POST);

// * Delete multiple via checkboxes * START *
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) { 
    if(is_array($_POST['delete'])) {
        foreach($_POST['delete'] as $value) { 
            if(intval($value)) {
                echo 'The order number '.$value.' has been deleted';
                $sql_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE ordNum = $value"); 
            }
        } 
    }
} elseif(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['product_choice'])) {
        foreach($_POST['product_choice'] as $key => $value) {
            if(intval($key)) {
                $sql_query = 'UPDATE '.$tbl_name.' SET product = "'.$_POST['product_choice'][$key].'", 
                              status = "'.$_POST['status_choice'][$key].'" WHERE ordNum = '.$key;
                echo $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Dropdown boxes:

```
<td>
<?//php echo $rows['product']; ?>
<select name="product_choice[<?php echo $rows['ordNum']?>] id="product" style="font-size:10px;">
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['product']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $rows['product']; ?></option>
            <option value="Color Correction"> Color Correction </option>
            <option value="Basic retouch"> Basic retouch </option>
            <option value="Extensive Retouch"> Extensive Retouch </option>
            <option value="Signature Work"> Signature Work </option>
            <option value="Signature Oil"> Signature Oil </option>
            <option value="Web Design"> Web Design </option>
            <option value="Print Design"> Print Design </option>
            <option value="Other"> Other </option>
          </select>

</td>

<td>
   <select name="status_choice[<?php echo $rows['ordNum']?>] id="status" style="font-size:10px;">

            <option value="<?php echo $rows['status']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $rows['status']; ?></option>
            <option value="Order Received"> Order Received </option>
            <option value="in the works"> in the works </option>
            <option value="waiting to upload"> waiting to upload </option>
            <option value="uploading"> uploading </option>
            <option value="ON HOLD"> ON HOLD </option>
            <option value="awaiting decision"> awaiting decision </option>
            <option value="proof sent"> proof sent </option>
            <option value="next invoice"> next invoice </option>
            <option value="waiting images/order"> waiting images/order </option>
            <option value="invoiced"> invoiced </option>
            <option value="complete"> complete </option>
            <option value="paid"> paid </option>
            <option value="making changes"> making changes </option>
          </select>

    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have a select in a loop with a static name

```
<select name="product_choice" id="product" style="font-size:10px;">
```

So you will have a bunch of select boxes with the identical name, so they will overwrite each other, and only the last one on the page will be correct.
You can either give them a unique name or make it an array.

This is same with your status one

```
<select name="status_choice" id="status" style="font-size:10px;">
```

So do something like

```
<select name="status_choice[<?=$rows['id']?>]>
```

Then to get the results..

```
foreach($_POST['product_choice'] as $key => $product)
{
    $status = $_POST['status_choice'][$key];
    $sql = sprintf('UPDATE test_orders SET product = "%s", status="%s" WHERE ordNum = %s', 
        mysql_real_escape_string($product), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status_choice'][$key]), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['checkbox'][$key]));
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());     
}
```

and then change your checkbox name to `checkbox[<?=$rows['product']?>]`

Comment: Ahhhhhh.  that makes sense.  So how would I get the post value then since I get it by name.
I can't do 

       $status = $_POST [' status_choice[<?=$rows['product']?>] ']
right?

Comment: I'm still having an issue with it only inserting the values from the bottom row. I updated my question at the bottom with my current code and issue. thanks.

Comment: You need to put your update statement in the foreach loops as well

Comment: I tried that before (and again to make sure) it still echos everything out fine the first time.  But the echo right before the UPDATE statement still echos only the value of the last row.  Not sure if it helps, but here's a link to the page http://chiseledimages.com/misc/test/checkstest2.php
you can choose some values and update and see what the echo looks like. thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Thanks again Kris. It works perfect now.  Learned some new stuff as well which is always good.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but it's not working perfectly.  I only tested with the first row before.  However when I put it into practice with my real site and table I noticed some issues. Came back to my test and sure enough it was happening there too.  The issue is now reversed from the beginning.  In the beginning the only values being inserted where from the last row.  Now the value that gets inserted is from the top row only.